# Task scheduler issue and reading Excel files

Tags: c#, excel, scheduled-tasks

I have an application which reads Excelfiles and converts them into text-files (tab delimeted).
It first copies the file from the source directory into a temp folder on the same machine (either my laptop or the server where it resides).
Locally the application works like it should.
I migrated the application to a windows 2012R2 server and tested with my account and it also works like it should
When I schedule it the applications has no access to the file c:\temp\tmp.xls. Exception info:

```
An exception occurred in class ExcelWorkbook, method SaveAsText_Tab. Exception info below:
    Microsoft Excel cannot access the file C:\TEMP\LUXINTRANET_JET_CUSTOMERS.xlsx. There are multiple reasons:

• The name of the file or path does not exist.
• The file is in use by another program.
• The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a workbook that is opened already.

       at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks.Open(String Filename, Object UpdateLinks, Object ReadOnly, Object Format, Object Password, Object WriteResPassword, Object IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Object Origin, Object Delimiter, Object Editable, Object Notify, Object Converter, Object AddToMru, Object Local, Object CorruptLoad)
   at ExcelHandler.Concrete.ExcelWorkbook.SaveAsText_Tab(String filename)
```

I've located the point of exception and it is in this line:

```
clsWorkbook = clsExcel.Workbooks.Open(filename);
```

Strange that it only happens when I run the application via the task scheduler and not via my own account.

The schedule is setup with my credentials, high priveleges.

I wrap my head around this for a few days now but it doesn't seem logical because I use the same user running it locally, on the server and via the Task Scheduler.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Excel sometimes attempts to use system user profile folders, which are non-existent. We have cured that by creating folder C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop (for 32-bit Windows) or C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop (for 64-bit Windows).

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer. I found this in other posts but only created the 64-bit part. The excel is 32-bit and I now created the ...system32\config\... folder and it works. Thanks Arvo!

Comment: Just tried the solution by @Arvo, it works. I think you should answer this so that it can accepted.

Comment: @NoshairwanFarooq Done, waiting for your action now :)

Answer (score 1):

Promoted from comment as requested:

Excel sometimes attempts to use system user profile folders, which are non-existent. We have cured that by creating folder C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop (for 32-bit Windows) or C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop (for 64-bit Windows).